# A proof of inequality about $L_{p}$ space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

everyone
I am reading a note and find a proof of an inequality. It says this,

By holder inequality, for $1\le p\lt\infty$,we have
\begin{align}
|\int_{R}|f(x-y)g(y)|dy|^{p} &\le (\int_{R}|f(x-y)|^{p}|g(y)|dy)(\int_{R}|g(y)|dy)^{p-1} \\ &=\|g\|_{L_{1}}^{p-1}\int_{R}|f(x-y)|^{p}|g(y)|dy
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int_{R}|\int_{R}|f(x-y)g(y)|dy|^{p}dx &\le \|g\|_{L_{1}}^{p-1}\int_{R}\int_{R}|f(x-y)|^{p}|g(x)|dydx \\&=\|g\|_{L_{1}}^{p-1}\int_{R}\int_{R}|f(x-y)|^{p}|g(x)|dxdy \\&=\|f\|_{L_{p}}^{p}\|g\|_{L_{1}}^{p}
\end{align}

What I don't understand is 1) How holder inequality can justify the first $\le$ sign in the first formula. It seems holder inequality does not work this way. 2) Why the doulbe integral in the second line of the second formula equals to $\|f\|_{L_{p}}^{p}\|g\|_{L_{1}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Q1, if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then $|g(y)|=|g(y)|^{\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}}=|g(y)|^{\frac{1}{p}}|g(y)|^{\frac{1}{q}}$, apply Holder's inquality to $|f(x-y)||g(y)|^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $|g(y)|^{\frac{1}{q}}$ gives you the result.

For Q2, just use Fubini's theorem to interchange the integration ( integrate w.r.t $y$ first), and the use Change of variable formula.

Comment: Thanks. Then it is clearer:-( It seems easier than I thought. So I think the second line of the second formula where it changes $dydx$ to $dxdy$ is a bit redundant. Right?

Comment: @Hua At least to me, yes.